# How do I remove unwanted scrollbar that appears when using "sap.f.ShellBar" for custom launchpads?

Tags: sapui5

A scrollbar appears always if `sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer` height is 100%, on screens of Notebook-size or smaller if 95%. Page endings look out of position if set below 95%. Auto-size won't work.

How to get rid of the scrollbar?

In `index.html`:

```js
// On core init:
new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
    height: "95%",
    name: "MyApp",
}).placeAt("content");
```

In `App.view.xml`

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.f"
    height="100%"
    displayBlock="true">
    <f:ShellBar title="MyApp">
    </f:ShellBar>
    <Shell>
        <App id="app">
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

My intention is to create my own version of a launchpad container to host other apps.
**UI5 version:** latest stable SAPUI5 release

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the approachs in samples [Shell Bar with Flexible Column Layout](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.f.ShellBar/sample/sap.f.sample.ShellBarWithFlexibleColumnLayout) or [Shell Bar with Split App](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.f.ShellBar/sample/sap.f.sample.ShellBarWithSplitApp)

[sap.m.Shell](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/4df1d914e52d4b1aa0805eb01522537e) does not appear to play well when there are sibling controls in the page. It is usually used as the top container in the page.